# How to use .apply() to combine a column of dictionaries into one dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of dictionaries within a pandas data frame.

```
srs_tf = pd.Series([{'dried': 1, 'oak': 2},{'fruity': 2, 'earthy': 2},{'tones': 2, 'oak': 4}]) 
srs_b = pd.Series([2,4,6]) 
df = pd.DataFrame({'tf': srs_tf, 'b': srs_b}) 

df

                           tf  b
0      {'dried': 1, 'oak': 2}  2
1  {'fruity': 2, 'earthy': 2}  4
2      {'tones': 2, 'oak': 4}  6
```

These dictionaries represent word frequency in descriptions of wines (Ex input dictionary:{'savory': 1, 'dried': 3, 'thyme': 1, 'notes':..}). I need to create an output dictionary from this column of dictionaries that contains all of the keys from the input dictionaries and maps them to the ***number of input dictionaries*** in which those keys are present. For example, the word 'dried' is a key in 850 of the input dictionaries, so in the output dictionary {.. 'dried': 850...}.

I want to try using the data frame .apply() method but I believe that I am using it incorrectly.

```
def worddict(row, description_counter):
    for key in row['tf'].keys():
        if key in description_counter.keys():
            description_counter[key] += 1
        else:
            description_counter[key] = 1
    return description_counter

description_counter = {}

output_dict = df_wine_list.apply(lambda x: worddict(x, description_counter), axis = 1)
```

So a couple things. I think that my axis should = 0 rather than 1, but I get this error when I try that: KeyError: ('tf', 'occurred at index Unnamed: 0')

When I do use axis = 1, my function returns a column of identical dictionaries rather than a single dictionary.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output?

Comment: `srs_tf = pd.Series([{'dried': 1, 'oak': 2},{'fruity': 2, 'earthy': 2},{'tones': 2, 'oak': 4}])
srs_b = pd.Series([2,4,6])
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': srs_tf, 'b': srs_b})
df` Output dict should be {'dried': 1, 'oak': 2, 'fruity': 1, 'earthy': 1}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `chain` and `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

Counter(chain.from_iterable(df['a']))
# Counter({'dried': 1, 'earthy': 1, 'fruity': 1, 'oak': 2, 'tones': 1})
```

Or,

```
Counter(y for x in df['a'] for y in x)
# Counter({'dried': 1, 'earthy': 1, 'fruity': 1, 'oak': 2, 'tones': 1})
```

---

You can also use `Index.value_counts`,

```
pd.concat(map(pd.Series, df['a'])).index.value_counts().to_dict()
# {'dried': 1, 'earthy': 1, 'fruity': 1, 'oak': 2, 'tones': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason that I can't quite grasp, when I use your code my output dictionary is exactly like the column of identical dictionaries that my .apply() code returned, except the values are all divided by 2.

Comment: @mpollinger Are you by any chance doing this inside a `groupby`?

Comment: @mpollinger In that case I couldn't tell you why, I'm afraid. I can, however guarantee that this is correct.